# Как получить размеры SVG посредством JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, svg

Пытаюсь получить ширину SVG.

1. `svg.getBBox().width()` --> 40. Нашел ширину круга без учета stroke.
2. `svg.width` --> Сложный объект, в котором нахожу свойство animVal и baseVal, содержащих свойство value: 300
3. `svg.width.animVal.value` --> 300. Получаю искомое, правда иногда и 0.

Есть ли способ получить размер SVG эффективнее и надёжнее в плане результата?

Потому как, далее имею следующее: меняю через стили размеры SVG, а `svg.width.animVal.value` "не успевает" обновиться. Иногда успевает. После вызова кода с небольшой задержкой (10ms) все нормально.

```js
let svg = document.getElementById('_svg');

console.log(`BBox.width: ${svg.getBBox().width}`);
console.log(`SVG.width: ${svg.width}`); // Получаю сложный объект
printWidth();

svg.style.width = '600px';
svg.style.height = '200px';

printWidth();

setTimeout(printWidth, 10);

function printWidth(){
    console.log(`SVG.width.animVal.value: ${svg.width.animVal.value}`);
    console.log(`SVG.width.baseVal.value: ${svg.width.baseVal.value}`);
}
```

```html
<svg fill="yellow" stroke="black" id="_svg">
    <circle cx="25" cy="25" r="20"/> 
</svg>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24649456/407561 не пробовал?

Comment: @NMD спасибо, работает. Жаль, что не самообновляемый объект возвращает, после изменения параметров SVG приходится запрашивать `getBoundingClientRect` снова. A `svg.getClientRects()[0].width` до явного задания размеров (`svg.style.width`) вообще возвращает undefined.

Comment: @NMD, кстати, самый популярный ответ там: `getBBox()`, с которого я начал, и который возвращает габариты содержимого холста, а не самого SVG. Впрочем, это тоже крайне полезный метод) Оформите ответ, пожалуйста.

Comment: Пожалуйста, тоже увидел про getBBox(), но потом вижу, что у вас в коде, он уже используется и еще немного по искал и нашел данный метод. Ответ конечно у меня уровень бог)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> svg.getBBox().width() --> 40 ??? Нашел ширину круга без учета stroke???

Да.

> svg.width.animVal.value --> 300 !!!! Получаю искомое, правда иногда и 0???

`animVal` - во время анимации - содержит текущее значение атрибута. Вероятно, ваш код в такие моменты выполнялся раньше, чем успевал отобразиться круг.

> Есть ли способ получить размер SVG эффективнее и надёжнее в плане результата?

Можно использовать `getBoundingClientRect()`:

```
console.log(`Width: ${svg.getBoundingClientRect().width}`);
console.log(`Height: ${svg.getBoundingClientRect().height}`);
```

Comment: @Leonid , Да, вы правы. Удивительно, что Chrome DevTools показывал те же самые размеры элемента, при этом выделяя весь контур. Исправил

Answer (score 5):

```
var el   = document.getElementById("yourElement"); // or other selector like querySelector()
var rect = el.getBoundingClientRect(); // get the bounding rectangle

console.log( rect.width );
console.log( rect.height);
```

[Ссылка на первоисточник](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24649456/407561)

Answer (score 2):

**Вариант №1:** использовать `getBBox()`. Он сообщает ширину и высоту, смещение `x` и `y` в пикселях без учёта масштабирования элемента – то есть `getBBox()` получает начальные размеры:

```js
const el = document.getElementById('_svg')
console.log(el.getBBox().width)
console.log(el.getBBox().height)
```

```html
<svg fill="yellow" stroke="black" viebox="0 0 600 200" id="_svg">
  <circle cx="25" cy="25" r="20"/> 
</svg>
```

**Вариант №2:** использовать `getBoundingClientRect()` – он учитывает преобразования, выполненные с помощью масштаба и т.д:

```js
const el = document.getElementById('_svg')
console.log(el.getBoundingClientRect().width)
console.log(el.getBoundingClientRect().height)
```

```html
<svg fill="yellow" stroke="black" viebox="0 0 600 200" id="_svg">
  <circle cx="25" cy="25" r="20"/> 
</svg>
```